# Group data by houly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, aggregate, grouping

I have three columns, `Date`, `Time`, and `Production Total`. I want group them together and get the sum of each hourly interval filtered by date and also avg of each summed up hourly interval by date.

sample data

```
Date        Time    Production total
11/30/2016  7:29    5
11/30/2016  7:35    6
11/30/2016  8:05    5
11/30/2016  8:11    5
12/1/2016   0:04    5
12/1/2016   0:10    6
12/1/2016   1:04    6
12/1/2016   1:10    5
12/2/2016   6:52    5
12/2/2016   6:58    4
12/2/2016   7:04    5
12/2/2016   7:10    5
```

I want the results to be something like

```
Date        Time    Production total
11/30/2016  7:00    11
11/30/2016  8:00    10  
12/1/2016   0:00    11
12/1/2016   1:00    11
12/2/2016   6:00    9
12/2/2016   7:00    10
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? `DATEPART()` and `GROUP BY` are your friends

Comment: yes but i don't know where to start since group by doesn't work..

Comment: Post what you have started.

Comment: Define doesn't work. Please share the info what you have in order to help us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DatePart to get Hour and use group by to sum

```
select [date], datepart(hour,[time]), sum([production total]) from #yourtable
group by [date], datepart(hour, [time])
```

Table contents:

```
create table #yourtable ( Date date, time time, [Production Total] int)

insert into #yourtable (
[Date],     [Time]  ,[Production total] ) values
 ('11/30/2016'  ,'7:29',    5 )
,('11/30/2016'  ,'7:35',    6 )
,('11/30/2016'  ,'8:05',    5 )
,('11/30/2016'  ,'8:11',    5 )
,('12/1/2016'   ,'0:04',    5 )
,('12/1/2016'   ,'0:10',    6 )
,('12/1/2016'   ,'1:04',    6 )
,('12/1/2016'   ,'1:10',    5 )
,('12/2/2016'   ,'6:52',    5 )
,('12/2/2016'   ,'6:58',    4 )
,('12/2/2016'   ,'7:04',    5 )
,('12/2/2016'   ,'7:10',    5 )
```